# Removing features from the Google Earth Plugin in c#

Tags: c#, google-earth-plugin

Using the Visual Studio C# Winforms Google Earth plugin, 4 placemarks have been added to the globe as can be seen in the picture below:

[image]

My goal is to be able to remove the linestring placemark.  The steps would seem to be to get all the placemarks, find the linestring and remove it.

Here is the code being used to create the linestring placemarks (more or less from the API website)

```
    var lineStringPlacemark = ge2.createPlacemark("Line_" + name);
    // create the line string geometry
    var lineString = ge2.createLineString("");
    lineStringPlacemark.setGeometry(lineString);
    // add the the points to the line string geometry
    double dlat1 = Convert.ToDouble(lat1) / 100000;
    double dlon1 = Convert.ToDouble(lon1) / 100000;
    double dlat2 = Convert.ToDouble(lat2) / 100000;
    double dlon2 = Convert.ToDouble(lon2) / 100000;
    lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(dlat1, dlon1, 0);
    lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(dlat2, dlon2, 0);

    // Create a style and set width and color of line
    lineStringPlacemark.setStyleSelector(ge2.createStyle(""));
    var lineStyle = lineStringPlacemark.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();
    lineStyle.setWidth(5);
    lineStyle.getColor().set("9900ffff");  // aabbggrr format
    // Add the feature to Earth
    ge2.getFeatures().appendChild(lineStringPlacemark);
```

And here is the code I ended up using to remove the line.  Note that the GEHelpers.RemoveFeatureById(ge2, s); is commented out since it isn't working for me for some reason.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ge2.getFeatures().getChildNodes().getLength(); i++)
{
   var kmlobject = ge2.getFeatures().getChildNodes().item[i];
   string s = kmlobject.getId();

   if (s.Contains("Line_"))
   {                
      ge2.getFeatures().removeChild(kmlobject);
      kmlobject.release();
      //GEHelpers.RemoveFeatureById(ge2, s);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line you have should work and remove all the currently loaded content.

```
GEHelpers.RemoveAllFeatures(ge); // removes all loaded features from 'ge'
```

If you wish to remove a specific placemark, or any other feature, simply specify its ID as the parameter to the `RemoveFeatureById` method.

```
GEHelpers.RemoveFeatureById(ge, 'foo'); // remove the feature with the id 'foo'
```

An ID can be set either when you create the feature via the api or when you define the feature in kml. e.g.

```
// api
ge.createPlacemark('foo');

//kml id
<Document id="foo">
</Document>
```

Edit:

You should not have to do anything other than...

```
for (int i = 0; i < ge2.getFeatures().getChildNodes().getLength(); i++)
{
   var kmlobject = ge2.getFeatures().getChildNodes().item[i];
   if (kmlobject.getId().Contains("Line_"))
   {                
      ge2.getFeatures().removeChild(kmlobject);
   }
}
```

I think that there is possibly something else going on with your set up, maybe to do with having multiple instances of the plugin running at the same time.

Comment: Hi Fraser and thanks for responding. The argument being passed into both functions is a 'ge' - I call it 'ge1'.  I have another one called 'ge2'.

I was planning to use the GetAllFeatures to get the IDs and compare them to the known ID and use the RemoveFeatureById with the ID that matched.

Comment: If you have a known ID then you can simply use that to remove the feature via RemoveFeatureById. In any case you don't need to call GetAllFeaturesKml - it is of no use to you at all here.

Comment: also, you are using an old version of the library by the look of things. You should try updating to the latest version.

Comment: For some reason the RemoveFeatureById is not working either.  The getElementById is returning null.  I ended up just going through all the children and deleting the right one when I found it.  I keep looking at the svn repository at (http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/source/browse/) but it still shows a build date of Nov. 20, 2012.  That's the version I have.  Is there another place to get newer source code?

Comment: Are you sure the element has an ID? You don't show in your question how you create or load your features, please show your code/kml.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Fraser.  I updated the question to show both the code to create and the code to remove.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25224/discussion-between-fraser-and-cramertv)